# How do you copy a string to a different string?

Tags: c++, string, function, c-strings

I am writing a function that removes vowels from a string (users name), and will then pass that function into another function that prints out the name without vowels. In order to copy the `input[i]` to the `outputNoVowels`, would this be the correct way of doing it?

```cpp
string removeVowels(string input) {
    string outputNoVowels;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
        switch (input[i]) {
        case 'a':
            break;
        case 'e':
            break;
        case 'i':
            break;
        case 'o':
            break;
        case 'u':
            break;
        case 'A':
            break;
        case 'E':
            break;
        case 'I':
            break;
        case 'O':
            break;
        case 'U':
            break;
        default:
            outputNoVowels = input[i];

        }
    }
    return outputNoVowels;
}
```

How come, when the program runs, it only prints out one letter in the string?

Provided Algorithm:

[image]

This is what is printing in the console window:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**: how would I do the same for `char[]` strings?

```cpp
void removeVowels(const char input[], char output[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input) - 1; i++) {
        switch (input[i]) {
        case 'a':
            break;
        case 'e':
            break;
        case 'i':
            break;
        case 'o':
            break;
        case 'u':
            break;
        case 'A':
            break;
        case 'E':
            break;
        case 'I':
            break;
        case 'O':
            break;
        case 'U':
            break;
        default:
            strcpy(output, input);
            strcat(output, input);
        }
    }
}
```

Provided Algorithm:

[image]

Comment: FYI -- One line of code with `std::remove_if` replaces that entire `switch`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie alternatively, `std::copy_if()` with `std::back_inserter`

Comment: @wackflapjack Please do not edit a question in a way that invalidates existing comments/answers. If you have new information to add, append it to the end of the existing question instead. I have reverted your edit and have reworded it for it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 1 letter in the output because you are **assigning** each letter to `outputNoVowels` via its `=` assignment operator, wiping out its current content each time, so there is at most only 1 letter in `outputNoVowels` upon `return`.

You need to instead **append** each letter to `outputNoVowels`, via its `+=` operator (or its `push_back()` or `append()` method), thus preserving any existing content.

Also, your loop is ignoring the last character in the `input` string. There is a typo in the instructions.

Try this instead:

```
string removeVowels(const string &input) {
    string outputNoVowels;
    const size_t len = input.length();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        switch (input[i]) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                break;
            default:
                outputNoVowels += input[i];
                // or: outputNoVowels.push_back(input[i]);
                // or: outputNoVowels.append(1, input[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
    return outputNoVowels;
}
```

That being said, you can eliminate the `switch` altogether by using the standard `std::copy_if()` algorithm instead (with `std::back_inserter` as the destination), eg:

```
string removeVowels(const string &input) {    
    static const string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    string outputNoVowels;
    copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
        back_inserter(outputNoVowels),
        [&](char ch){ return vowels.find(ch) == string::npos; }
    );
    return outputNoVowels;
}
```

Or, by using the `std::remove_if()` algorithm, eg:

```
string removeVowels(string input) {    
    static const string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    input.erase(
        remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
            [&](char ch){ return vowels.find(ch) != string::npos; }
        ),
        input.end()
    );
    return input;
}
```

Or, by using the `std::erase_if()` algorithm (C++20 and later), eg:

```
string removeVowels(string input) {    
    static const string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    erase_if(input,
        [&](char ch){ return vowels.find(ch) != string::npos; }
    );
    return input;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: in your `char[]` version, you have the opposite problem. You are *appending* **too many** letters to the output string.  For each letter you want to keep, you are assigning the entire input string to the output, and then appending the entire input string to the end, rather than just the 1 letter.

You can use techniques similar to above to solve the `char[]` version, eg:

```
void removeVowels(const char input[], char output[]) {
    int idx = 0;
    const int len = strlen(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        switch (input[i]) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                break;
            default:
                output[idx++] = input[i];
                break;
        }
    }
    output[idx] = '\0';
}
```

Or, using the `std::copy_if()` algorithm:

```
void removeVowels(const char input[], char output[]) {    
    static const char[] vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    static const char*  vowels_end = vowels + strlen(vowels);
    char* output_end = copy_if(input, input + strlen(input),
        output,
        [&](char ch){ return find(vowels, vowels_end, ch) == vowels_end; }
    );
    *output_end = '\0';
}
```

Comment: This has been super helpful! I appreciate the detailed comments. I'm really new to coding and am trying to get some c++ under my belt - I heard it's a good language to learn that makes learning others a tad bit easier. THANKS AGAIN!